# malfunction or burglar?

Tags: doors, garage-door-opener

I everyone, I have a complicated situation so please bare with me for a minute. Years ago our garage door started to go up by its self. I was thinking about replacing the opener but when I looked online at some of the reviews I decide to just pull the  emergency release cord and manually  pull the door up and down. I closed it with chains tied on the frame  on the inside   Anyway this morning i find my garage door pulled up about 4 inches  The door was so jammed up that I had to take the lock off the chain but I couldn't unroll the chain from where i had it tied  so I had to  use  the  claw part of the hammer to pull loose the chain. It was so pulled up the metal bar that the door slides up on was bending.   When I finally got the chains off the door it  went up a inch or so more and I couldn't get it back down. I pulled the   emergency release cord and the door could be pulled down a little but stoped so I had to pull the cord again, finally I pulled the cord and taped it  and used some clips to hold it in the  release position ,  Anyway my question is this could the  Emergency Cord some how reset its self and the motor malfunctioned again and the door tried to open but was stopped by the chains?

Comment: Time for motion sensing lights and cameras on the outside of the garage. I’ve read plenty of stories of how garage doors openers were easily overridden by burglars; not sure if this is still an issue on newer openers though.

Comment: Anything “could” happen it I doubt a release could reset itself. Many people don’t know it but most garage doors are easy to force open. The brackets that connect to the mechanism are only sheet metal. I agree with unhandledexcepsean +